# Quiero que los elementos Hijo que están dentro de Padre se vean solo 3 por línea

Tags: html, css, css3, responsive, div

Quiero que se vean nomás 3 cuadros por línea y se ven los 3 primeros inicial (bien) ya en la linea de abajo se ve uno y hay muchos más pero todos están debajo de ese y no entiendo como alinearlos:(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.contenedor{
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(18deg, rgba(117,123,255,1) 0%, rgba(109,145,254,1) 50%, rgba(129,209,255,1) 100%);
    height: 500vh;
    width: 100%;
    border: red 1px solid;
}
.contenido{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 370px;
    height: 400px;
    border: white solid 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5) 20%, rgba(238, 130, 238, 0.5) 80%);
}
```

---

```
<body>
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (mafioso)</h1>
        <img id="XDMafioso" src="fotos/xd(mafia).png">
        <p>Fumador de Nicotina profresional, habilidad para bicicletear 98%, y -35 en visión de juego</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (normal)</h1>
        <img id="xdNormal" src="fotos/xd.jpeg">
        <p>Este también es xd, solo que esta versión no fuma, es saludable y tiene una relación estable</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (marushi)</h1>
        <img id="marushi" src="fotos/Marushi.jpeg">
        <p>Este es la combinación entre XD, y DX, tímido pero buena persona, es fanático de lo sensual</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XDXD</h1>
        <img id="xd" src="fotos/xda.png">
        <p>Animador profesional, xd en todas las redes sociales, tiene un queso impresionante, amante de barinas</p>
```

Comment: añade tu codigo html, seria de gran ayuda

Comment: Puedes usar Flex box? Con eso se soluciona.

Answer (score 0):

Le recomiendo aprender grid css: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp, es muy fácil de entender y se pueden hacer cosas como estas de manera muy rápida y simple (ver resultado en página completa):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
.contenedor{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
    
    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (mafioso)</h1>
        <img id="XDMafioso" src="fotos/xd(mafia).png">
        <p>Fumador de Nicotina profresional, habilidad para bicicletear 98%, y -35 en visión de juego</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (normal)</h1>
        <img id="xdNormal" src="fotos/xd.jpeg">
        <p>Este también es xd, solo que esta versión no fuma, es saludable y tiene una relación estable</p>
    </div>
    
     <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (normal)</h1>
        <img id="xdNormal" src="fotos/xd.jpeg">
        <p>Este también es xd, solo que esta versión no fuma, es saludable y tiene una relación estable</p>
    </div>
    
     <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (normal)</h1>
        <img id="xdNormal" src="fotos/xd.jpeg">
        <p>Este también es xd, solo que esta versión no fuma, es saludable y tiene una relación estable</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XD (marushi)</h1>
        <img id="marushi" src="fotos/Marushi.jpeg">
        <p>Este es la combinación entre XD, y DX, tímido pero buena persona, es fanático de lo sensual</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contenido">
        <h1>XDXD</h1>
        <img id="xd" src="fotos/xda.png">
        <p>Animador profesional, xd en todas las redes sociales, tiene un queso impresionante, amante de barinas</p>
    </div>
</div>
```